# How do you update a data blob column by searching and replacing a string using drush?

Tags: drush, database

How would one do the following in drush? I want to change some data in one of the users table for one of my users. The thing I want to change is in the data blob column with all the punctuation's and what not. I can copy the data blob out, edit, it and then paste it back in, but was wondering how can this be done via drush with a search and replace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following MySQL statement in the drush SQL console:

```
drush sqlq "update users set data = replace(data, 'string_here', replacement_string') where uid = 1"
```